# Why @Data and @Builder doesnt work together

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I have this simple  class

```
public class ErrorDetails {
    private String param = null;
    private String moreInfo = null;
    private String reason = null;
     ...
}
```

After refactoring, I added `@Data` and `@Builder`, but all the instantiations doesn't work any more

```
ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails();
```

> 'ErrorDetails(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
>   is not public in
>   'com.nordea.openbanking.payments.common.ndf.client.model.error.ErrorDetails'.
>   Cannot be accessed from outside package

If I removed `@Builder`, then it will work fine, 
Why I cannot use `@Data` and `@Builder` together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lombok's `@Builder` [must have](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1389) `@AllArgsConstructor` in order to work

> Adding also @AllArgsConstructor should do

Under the hood it build all fields using [constructor with all fields](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)

> applying `@Builder` to a class is as if you added `@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PACKAGE)` to the class and applied the `@Builder` annotation to this all-args-constructor. This only works if you haven't written any explicit constructors yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The full config should be :

```
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
class ErrorDetails {
    private String param; // no need to initiate with null
    private String moreInfo;
    private String reason;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why i should use all of these annotations ?

Comment: Must you add `toBuilder = true`?

Comment: @user7294900 no, but in some cases it is important, I use that because I got some issue when I use it without toBuilder check my post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349077/lombok-builder-pattern-in-multiple-shots